# select distinct from join

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Tables look like this

```
Table 1               Table 2
Users                 Options  

id name               id     user_id   option   
-------               ---   --------   --------
1  Donald             1     1          access1
2  John               2     1          access2
3  Bruce              3     1          access3
4  Paul               4     2          access1
5  Ronald             5     2          access3
6  Steve              6     3          access1
```

Now, i want to select join these to find a user which has only **access1**
If i do something like

```
select t1.id,t1.name,t2.id,t2.user_id,t2.option 
from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.id=t2.user_id
and option='access1';
```

This does not give me unique results, as in the example i need only **user_id=3** my data has has these in hundreds

I also tried something like

```
select user_id from table2 where option='access1'
and user_id not in (select user_id from table2 where option<>'access1')
```

There have been other unsuccessful attempts too but i am stuck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a EXISTS subquery (technically, a left semijoin):

```
SELECT  id, name
FROM    table1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM table2
    WHERE   table1.id = table2.user_id
      AND   table2.option = 'access1'
)
```

If you want only users that have access1 and not any other access, add NOT EXISTS (a left anti-semi-join; there's a term to impress your colleagues!):

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table2
    WHERE   table1.id = table2.user_id
      AND   table2.option <> 'access1'
)
```

Comment: I tried, the not exists option in this scheme is giving me 0 rows

Comment: Tried again with some changes, in NOT EXISTS i used `AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table2
    WHERE   table1.id = table2.user_id
      AND   table2.option = 'access1'` which seems to work but i haven't verified the data yet

Comment: Just fyi, NOT EXISTS is really just an antijoin. It's the complement to the semijoin.

Comment: An antijoin returns unmatched data from either side. This only returns values on the left that aren't on the right, hence a semi-join. Left-Anti-Semi-Join is what SQL Server calls this anyway. If I still have my terminology wrong, please provide a reference.

Comment: Wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antijoin. I'm not aware of a named join type that returns unmatched data from either side. Maybe the SQL Server docs call it a left anti-semijoin because it is the complement of the semi-join, but I'm struggling to imagine a right anti-semijoin, and I think antijoin is the formal term.

Comment: Fair enough. MSSQL usage looks incorrect. I suppose the "unmatched data from either side" would be called a "full antijoin" but I haven't seen that defined (I've used them, though!)

Comment: Or an "anti full outer join"! Sounds like a monstrosity.

Answer (score 1):

[`bool_and`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) makes it simple

```
with users (id,name) as ( values
    (1,'donald'),
    (2,'john'),
    (3,'bruce'),
    (4,'paul'),
    (5,'ronald'),
    (6,'steve')
), options (id,user_id,option) as ( values
    (1,1,'access1'),
    (2,1,'access2'),
    (3,1,'access3'),
    (4,2,'access1'),
    (5,2,'access3'),
    (6,3,'access1')
)
select u.id, u.name
from
    users u
    inner join
    options o on o.user_id = u.id
group by 1, 2
having bool_and(o.option = 'access1')
;
 id | name  
----+-------
  3 | bruce
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user that has only access1, I would use aggregation:

```
select user_id
from table2
group by user_id
having min(option) = max(option) and min(option) = 'access1';
```

Comment: This doesn't return the name, and doesn't join to the primary key table (we don't know that referential integrity is being enforced). It's also quite expensive, because computing the min and max of a column like this requires either sorting or building a temporary table.

Comment: I agree with @cliffordheath aggregation would be expensive for me, but i will try it anyway

Comment: I used the aggregation and it returns 0 rows as well

Comment: Although this requires sorting, when extended to join the two tables it does so quite efficiently. The most efficient way of using exists and not exists for this type of query is very often to use hash joins, which require two scans of the table referenced in the correlated subquery, so it's guaranteed to be super fast. The difference between the methods probably depends on the proportion of rows in table2 with 'access1' -- if it was very small then the anti/semijoin would probably win, otherwise I'd try the aggregation.

Comment: @cliffordheath . . . Postgres supports hash aggregates and now I think it will even use indexes for aggregation.  Hence, your comment is not correct.

Comment: A hash aggregate is the same as an in-memory temporary table; it's a hash table. It uses storage, and that has a cost. It also relies on there being enough RAM available (a good bet, these days, but still).

Comment: It's obviously a matter of testing for particular situations, and this answer should not have been downvoted.

Comment: @DavidAldridge . . . I don't disagree at all.  Clifford's comment was a universal statement that this method would have bad performance; it was not a statement that performance should be tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH users(id,name) AS ( VALUES
  (1,'Donald'),
  (2,'John'),
  (3,'Bruce'),
  (4,'Paul'),
  (5,'Ronald'),
  (6,'Steve')
), options(id,user_id,option) AS ( VALUES
  (1,1,'access1'),
  (2,1,'access2'),
  (3,1,'access3'),
  (4,2,'access1'),
  (5,2,'access3'),
  (6,3,'access1')
), user_access_count AS (
  SELECT op.user_id,count(op.option) AS access_count
  FROM options op
  WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM options
    WHERE option = 'access1'
  )
  GROUP BY op.user_id
)
SELECT u.id,u.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_access_count uac ON uac.user_id = u.id
WHERE uac.access_count = 1;
```